# Is an NSError reusable?

Tags: ios

e.g.

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([something error:&error]) {
   // ...
}    
// ...

if ([somethingElse error:&error]) {
  // ...
}
```

Will I run into any problems if I use the same NSError without resetting it to nil?

Ordinarily I'd say it doesn't matter, but I worry that someone else would use one error when they meant to use the other.

Comment: In the example code, wouldn't the scope of the two code blocks be different, such that `error` would refer to distinct pointers?

Comment: In this form, you will get "use of undeclared identifier: error" on the last if statement.

Answer (score 2):

No problems, but to do that check error before passing the same pointer as argument. If the something method has an error and the somethingElse too, the error variable will have a pointer to the second one. Think you pass a pointer to a pointer to an object.

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([something error:&error]) {
   // ...
}    

if (error) {
//...
}

if ([somethingElse error:&error]) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will have problems with it. Your `NSError` variable will be rassigned only.